# in C programming and in Linux environment, how to get the size of an array of integers with some of the items = 0

Tags: arrays, c, linux, function

I have a simple function that gets an array of integers as its argument. I don't want to pass the size of the array to the function. to find the size in the function I have done the below. However, my code treats the items with value 0 as NULL or '\0'.

and it returns 9 , it is not counting the last item with the value = 0

```
int32_t array_of_int[]={9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

void _array(int32_t arr[]){

  size_t size_of_the_array = 0;

  while(*arr != '\0'){
    arr++;
    size_of_the_array++;
  }

  printf("size of the array = %lu\n", size_of_the_array );
  
}


_array(array_of_int);
```

Many thanks,

I have tied to tweak the code in different ways so the last item is not treated as a NULL or '\0' , but it didn't work.

I know that in c arrays are terminated with '\0'

Comment: "I know that in C, arrays are terminated with '\0'." -- No. What you are thinking of are *strings*, a special case of char arrays.

Comment: you are correct